# Why I get opposite brackets at listing code?

Tags: listings, code, hebrew

I'm writing Hebrew document and the brackets at the code are opposite.
They are ok at the regular mode but when I change the font style the brackets became opposite:
[image]

And here is MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Bellefair}


\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}


\begin{document}
\begin{english}[variant=american]%
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python,numbers=left,basicstyle={\ttfamily}]
a=(1)
b=[2]
\end{lstlisting}
\end{english}%

\end{document}
```

Do you know how to fix it?
Thank you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to switch explicitly to the latin tt:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}


\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}


\begin{document}

\begin{english}[variant=american]%

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python,numbers=left,basicstyle={\ttfamilylatin}]
a=(123)
b=[2]
\end{lstlisting}
\end{english}%

\end{document}
```

[image]